# InfluxDB port 8088

Tags: influxdb

Just installed **InfluxDB v.1.1.0** on CentOS, but when I try to start the service it complains about port **8088** already being in use by another application:

```
[run] 2016/11/28 13:50:54 InfluxDB starting, version 1.1.0, branch master, commit 800da5732b91c816b0a097acf8887fa2af1efa1a
[run] 2016/11/28 13:50:54 Go version go1.7.3, GOMAXPROCS set to 4
[run] 2016/11/28 13:50:54 Using configuration at: /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
run: open server: listen: listen tcp :8088: bind: address already in use
```

Where is this port configured and how do I change it? There's nothing mentioned about it in `/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found [6286](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/6286) on Github.

Running `influxd config | head -n 10` gives you the configuration.

Adding `bind-address = ":<port>"` somewhere at the top of the file in `/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf` solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was trying to start it twice:

```
/bin/systemctl start influxdb
influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
```

The first was unnecessary. Just use `influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf`